# Neutralizing "&" in Excel file

Tags: php, xml, excel

The question name is probably a bit confusing, so I'll try to clear it up. I have a database with some products, and a system of generating Excel xml files, to export these products and their prices. The problem is, when there is the "&" character in a database field (usually it's the product name), the excel file that is generated is "not well formed". The other thing is, that the database is pretty large, and some product names may contain "neutralized" & characters (for example `&amp`, or `&quot;`), but some don't, so I would have to do something like unescape and then escape to get what I need.
I have already tried with

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($name));
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Maybe this will help a bit more - I have a custom made "system" of exporting products to xls  files. They look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="Table1">
<Table>
<Column ss:Index="1" ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="110"/>

<Row>    
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Interna sifra</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Sifra</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> Naziv</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">MP cena</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">VP cena</Data></Cell>
</Row>

<Row>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">5263</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">03SL8733</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Speed Link slušalice sa mikrofonom IUNO Mono</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">0.00</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">733.04</Data></Cell>
</Row>

</Table>
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

except with a lot more rows. They are generated with php, by going through the database records, and echo-ing all the lines into an ExcelXML file. I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Then your system of generating the Excel files is broken, it probably doesn't have much to do with the database at all. What exactly are you doing? Also: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Ok, the system is working fine when there are no & characters in the database fields, it exports excel files which are perfectly usable.

Comment: Well, how and what kind of Excel files are you generating?! If you're generating XML, `&` is a special character that needs to be escaped to `&amp;` according to the XML spec. This should be happening automatically if you're using an XML writer library.

Comment: I have edited my question, hope it makes more sense now...

Comment: Then you need to escape all data according to XML escaping rules. Again, the best thing is to use an XML writer tool that worries about this for you.

Comment: It would be, but I can only make adjustments to the existing code, not make major changes such as changing the system alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe replacing yours & by \&

```
<?php
$name = str_replace("&", "\&", $name)
```

Last time I work with php I use this:

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

and I didn't have any problem

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. Now this would be great if I had only the & characters standing alone, that are giving me trouble. But the problem is that I have some already non-problematic & characters, which I mentioned above. So if I use str_replace, that would change both the ones that are giving me trouble, and the ones that don't...

Comment: you could try `str_replace(" & ", " \& ", $name)` , changing only freestanding &